# Can't modify global dict variable using mutliprocessing in python

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I try to use multiprocessing to process numpy array. But I don't know how to return the process result back to the dict variable.

Use the comments out code can produce what I expected. But when I try to use multiprocessing, I can't get anything for the `max_rslts`, it is an empty dict.

The example code is:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np

def calc_max(a, step):
    global max_rslts
    max_rslts[step] = a[::step].max()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_rslts = dict()

    a1 = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

#    for i in range(1,4):
#        calc_max(a1, i)
#    print(max_rslts)

    jobs = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        p = Process(target=calc_max, args=(a1, i))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print(a1)
    print(max_rslts)
```

Comment: Yes, multiprocessing does **not** share globals set after `__main__` has run. That's the nature of using multiple processes.

Comment: You might want to read [Exchanging objects between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) in the Multiprocessing documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`multiprocessing` programming guidelines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines):

> Avoid shared state

`global`s are not shared between processes after forking off each sub-process. Use different means to [share state between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) instead. A [`dict` manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) would work here:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import numpy as np


def calc_max(a, step, max_rslts):
    max_rslts[step] = a[::step].max()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    max_rslts = manager.dict()
    a1 = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
    jobs = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        p = Process(target=calc_max, args=(a1, i, max_rslts))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print(a1)
    print(max_rslts)
```